# No markdown diff on the new suggested edits page

Tags: support, suggested-edits

On the new Suggested Edits page, I saw an edit earlier that did not have the "markdown diffs" toggle available:

---

[image]

---

==> I moved to the next edit and it did have the option available:

---

[image]

---

- Is it a bug?
- If not why is there a difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The title is a plain text field; no markdown is interpreted in it. As such, there is no point in showing a markdown diff.

You'll see the same (no diff options) when reviewing suggested edits for tag excerpts, and when only the tags on a question have been changed.

In other words; this is no [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), but [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Answer (score 4):

Edits involving only title and/or tag will not have markdown diff.

Comment: That makes sense!